# Disable data binding for some layouts

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

Is it possible to disable Android data biding for some layouts ?

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true // not for all layout, possible ?
}
```

Comment: I would expect that if you have a layout resource without the root `<layout>` element, data binding is skipped.

Comment: What about in case of viewbinding? Is it possible not to use viewbinding for specific layout?

Comment: @NaumanAsh See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59998029/423105

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you don't wrap your layout with layout tag you don't use it

Answer (score 7):

If you want a layout file to be ignored while generating binding classes, add the tools:viewBindingIgnore="true" attribute to the root view of that layout file:

```
tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"
```

eg.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"
tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.