# How to Ignore view component(s) that I do not want to create bindings in Android view Binding library?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewbinder, android-viewbinding

I am exploring new [Android View Binding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

In my layout XML file, some views that I don't want to include in my binding class.

Does there any attribute or mechanism exist that exclude views into generated Binding class?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can use **`tools:viewBindingIgnore=”true/false”`** to include and exclude view in generated view binding class.

**Usage:**

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    tools:viewBindingIgnore="true" >
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Check more about View Binding on below link:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#setup

Comment: Much needed thing.

Comment: needs to be a way to do it true by default! Need to update hundreads of files.

Comment: I really appreciate it bro.